# Deploy multiple wars to WSO2 and each having multiple log4j configuration

Tags: java, maven, log4j, wso2, war

I need to deploy two wars into WSO2 server with different log4j.properties file for each war. but when I deploy second war to the server. it is overriding first war log4j configuration.(Goal is to maintain different logs for each war).

Can anybody help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure logging per web application. Read [This](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AS530/Customize+Logging+for+Web+Applications).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I do implement in the same way if I have a different app wars(different packages being pointed to different log file). Here the problem is, I have to deploy same app with version change and it is overriding the previous log4j.properties(pointed to externally located log4j1.properties to war1 and log4j2.properties -war2 files

Answer (score 0):

Bhathiya Thanks.. Initially it looked not possible with the link provided by you. But it got resolved with some pom changes.

Solution:  My pom.xml was pointing to wso2 logging dependency. so that was causing the issue to override war level log4j... I just removed server level log4j and added few log4j dependencies to the pom.xml and made it war level to work.

Now I can able to create versioned logs for same web app.

Thnaks